# How to make segwit transaction and bech32 mandatory

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, bech32-address

Is it possible to make segwit transactions (and possibly segwit address: Bech32) mandatory in the Bitcoin Core code?

In other words, when a transaction is created using the wallet, the transaction should be bech32 based segwit
and when a transaction is passed to the node, the node should ensure its a segwit transaction with bech32 addresses.

This is a hard fork of Bitcoin and I am considering changing the code

Comment: Do you mean in the wallet code (so applying to transactions created and accepted), or in the consensus rules (applying to all transactions in the network)?

Comment: Both, in other words, nothing but segwit addresses using bech32 should be created, accepted or parsed.

Comment: That requires a change to Bitcoin's network rules, which a vast agreement among the ecosystem. As such a change would break almost all wallet software, that seems highly unlikely to happen.

Comment: I am hard forking Bitcoin core by changing the code

Answer (score 1):

Bech32 is address encoding and cannot be enforced on the Bitcoin network as it is not part of the protocol.